# YouTube API v3: Liking a video with no channel set up

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have code that will "like" a video through the YouTube API v3.  At first, my code was throwing a 403 Forbidden error, and I tracked this down to the fact that my youtube account did not have a channel associated with it.  I created a channel by going to youtube.com, and clicking the "add to" link underneath a video.  A popup came up that said "Set up your channel to create your playlist on YouTube".  As soon as I filled out that form, and clicked continue, the code stopped returning a 403, and started working.

Is there anyway to "like" a video without having to go through this channel setup process?  Or if not, is there any way to tell if a user does not have a channel on their account, and prompt them to set it up if needed?

For reference, my code is written in python and is based off of the example here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/insert

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: There's now a [`channel.status.isLinked`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#status.isLinked) property which will reliably tell you whether a channel resource is "linked" in v3.

That being said, it is possible to like a video using the YouTube.com web interface for an account that doesn't have a channel, and I also believe that it was possible [using v2.1](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/10/introducing-google-account-support-and.html) of the legacy GData API. The fact that you can't do that in v3 sounds like a bug to me, and I'll escalate that internally.

Comment: Hey Jeff, thanks for the reply.  We just launched our youtube app, and many of our users have lightweight accounts.  Have you guys made any progress on this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, the bug for "like"ing in v3 remains open. One thing that will also change is that we'll be more clear about whether there's a lightweight account or not, by returning something explicit in the channel resource.

Comment: There's a new videos.rate() method which we're going to suggest developers start migrating to: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate Can you try that out?